# What is the indicial equation of this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is $$x^2 y''+xy'+\left(x^2-\frac{1}{9}\right)y=0.$$

Using Forbenius' Theorem I am getting two indicial equations, which are: ((-1/9)r^(2))a0 =0, and ((-1/9)+2r+r^(2)+1)a1 =0.

The question I'm looking at seems to imply that there is only one indicial equation though. Should I be getting two of them for this differential equation, or just one?

Answer (score 3):

The first one is the indical equation you are seeking (although you computed it incorrectly) and we can infer from the second equation that $a_1 = 0$ since they share no common roots.

Alternatively, for a differential equation of the form $P(x)y'' + Q(x)y' + R(x)y = 0$ the indical equation is given by $F(r) = r^2 + (p_0 - 1) + q_0$ where

$$p_0 = \lim_{x \to 0} x \frac{Q(x)}{R(x)} \ \text{and} \ q_0 = \lim_{x \to 0 } x^2 \frac{R(x)}{P(x)}$$

assuming they are both finite (which they are, by definition, if $x_0 = 0$ is an RSP).

Comment: I don't think I understand why I am able to ignore the second equation. Having two equations seems to imply that I will have 4 roots. Why is that not the case?

Comment: @IgnorantCuriosity That's true. But we're not ignoring the second equation. The only thing I'm saying is that the first equation is the *indical equation* (and there is only one). The other equation will be used later to solve the recurrence. Try working through the problem and let me know how it goes.